# How to move DataGridView row to another DataGridView in another form, with CSV Datasource- VB.net

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview

Im using a CSV to load data and save data from the DataGridView I have in a form. I would now like it so with a button click event I can send a row checked via the checkbox column on the DataGridView, to another dataGridView which is hosted in another form.

If it helps, here is the load im using to load and save the DataGridView contents.

```
Private Sub btnLoadDGVGeneral_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoadDGVGeneral.Click
    ' PURPOSE: Load CSV file containing tasks into DataGridView
    ' Clearing DGV Rows allows for Tasks to not double up when rebooting the program
    dataGVGeneral.Rows.Clear()
    'New Variable: fname, represents File Path of CSV as String
    Dim fname As String = "E:\SAT\Work.io\Work.io\bin\Debug\ListofTasks.csv"
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(fname, Encoding.Default)
    Dim sline As String = ""
    Dim colsexpected As Integer = 7
    Dim r As Integer = 0
    'StreamReader will the file Line by Line, and add it to the variable sline
    'First sline statement is Out of Loop, as first line of CSV contains headings to what each figure represents in a line.
    sline = reader.ReadLine
    Do
        'Now sline will read the 2nd line and so forth
        sline = reader.ReadLine
        'If no value is found on that line of the CSV file (at the end), then the loop will exit
        If sline Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        'Details is as a variable, which when called upon, places each value into different columns for that row
        Dim details() As String = sline.Split(",")
        dataGVGeneral.Rows.Add()
        For i As Integer = 0 To 6
            dataGVGeneral.Rows(r).Cells(i).Value = details(i)
        Next
        'Increments value of "r" by 1, meaning next line of CSV will be added to the next row.
        Dim v As Integer = r + 1
        r = v
    Loop
    reader.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSaveGeneralDGV_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveGeneralDGV.Click
    Dim StrExport As String = ""
    For Each C As DataGridViewColumn In dataGVGeneral.Columns
        StrExport &= """" & C.HeaderText & ""","
    Next
    StrExport = StrExport.Substring(0, StrExport.Length - 1)
    StrExport &= Environment.NewLine

    For Each R As DataGridViewRow In dataGVGeneral.Rows
        For Each C As DataGridViewCell In R.Cells
            If Not C.Value Is Nothing Then
                StrExport &= """" & C.Value.ToString & ""","
            Else
                StrExport &= """" & "" & ""","
            End If
        Next
        StrExport = StrExport.Substring(0, StrExport.Length - 1)
        StrExport &= Environment.NewLine
    Next

    Dim tw As System.IO.TextWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("E:\SAT\Work.io\Work.io\bin\Debug\ListofTasks.csv", False)
    tw.Write(StrExport)
    tw.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: If the columns are the same in both grids, you should be able to simply remove the row from one grid and add it to the other I would think. If the columns aren't the same, you can still get the appropriate cell values from the first grid, add a new row to the second grid with those values and then remove the row from the first grid. If you haven't tried to do either of those things then you haven't actually encountered an issue yet, so it's too soon to be posting here.

Comment: Wile yeah it's possible to do this directly via the DataGridView, wouldn't it really just make life simpler for you to read your data into a DataTable/DataSet and bind that to your DGV?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yeah the rows are all the same for both DataGridView's, do you know of any sample code I can follow, I am very stuck on this